# Kotlin FileWriter does not create any file

Tags: android, file, kotlin, filewriter

Hi I have tried to create file with FileWriter following this tutorial

https://medium.com/@ssaurel/parse-and-write-json-data-in-java-with-gson-dd8d1285b28

but i always get

```
   not fn
```

once i open the logcat which means that the file is never created.

I have not understood the matter.

Here is my code

```
fun writeJson()
{
    val item1 = InterItem(1, DateT(2018, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 6).date, "Dina", "type1")
    val  item2 = InterItem(2, DateT(2018, Calendar.MARCH, 8).date, "Lili", "type2")
    val item3= InterItem(3, DateT(2018, Calendar.MAY, 10).date, "Wassim", "type3")
    val res =  ListInter()
    res.list= arrayListOf( item1, item2, item3)
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
    val strJson = gson.toJson(res)
    var writer: FileWriter? = null
    try {
        writer = FileWriter("data.json")
        writer.write(strJson)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("errr","not fn")
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e("errr","not close")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want something like this `FileWriter(File(context.filesDir, "data.json"))` - you should provide the directory where you want the file placed. Also you can use `writer.use { it.write(strJson)}` as `FileWriter` implements `Closeable` - this handles closing the writer regardless of exception.

Comment: do u mean to give the name of the directory

Comment: How can i thank u i put this   `writer= FileWriter(File(this.filesDir, "data.json"))`  and it works. please answer the question may others take benifs too.God bless u

Comment: just if i do lie u have said i ommit all the tryes and cach. Can u update the solution please.And so thankful again and again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the code to this :

```
    try {
        val writer = FileWriter(File(this.filesDir, "data.json"))
        writer.use { it.write(strJson) }

    } catch (e : IOException){
        Log.e("errr","not fn", e)
    }
```

Should solve the issue. You should provide the directory where you want the file placed. Also you can use `writer.use { it.write(strJson)}` as `FileWriter` implements `Closeable` - this handles closing the writer regardless of exception.

Comment: There's no reason now to declare `writer` as nullable and mutable outside of the `try` block.